# Layout broken when change orientation in Android

Tags: android, layout, orientation, landscape

I am developing app for displaying a channel's live stream and it starts on landscape mode by default and I can change it to portrait and vice versa from my options menu

Now I am using this code in manifest and put it in that activity
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

When I start app, it is working fine but when I change orientation to portrait, the app is hanging and options menu doesn't disappear as usual.

if I deleted this part `|screenSize` from manifest, it is working fine but the layout-land doesn't work and portrait layout is used at both orientation.

This is LiveActivity.java

```
package com.shadatv.shada;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.VideoView;

public class LiveActivity extends Activity {
    VideoView videoView;

    private AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog;
    String httpLiveUrl = "http://38.96.148.147:1935/live/livestream/playlist.m3u8";

    // =============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.live);
        try {
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
            videoView.requestFocus();

            videoView
                    .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            videoView.seekTo(1000);
                            videoView.start();

                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            errorDialog.setMessage("مشكلة في البث");
            errorDialog.setCancelable(true);
            errorDialog.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        // click listener on the alert box
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog errorStream = errorDialog.create();
            errorStream.show();
        }
    }

    // =============================================================================

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_shada, menu);
        MenuItem fullItem = menu.findItem(R.id.fullScreen);
        MenuItem smallItem = menu.findItem(R.id.smallScreen);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            fullItem.setVisible(false);
            smallItem.setVisible(true);
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            smallItem.setVisible(false);
            fullItem.setVisible(true);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    // =============================================================================

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            // setContentView(R.layout.activity_shada);
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            // setContentView(R.layout.activity_shada1);
        }
    }

    // =============================================================================

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about: {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.shadatv.MainActivity"));
        }
            break;

        case R.id.smallScreen: {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
            break;

        case R.id.fullScreen: {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shadatv.shada"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/shada"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        >       
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LiveActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.shadatv.LiveActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by pull out the `setContentView` and `try/catch` block from `onCreate` and put it `onConfigChanged`

```
package com.shadatv.shada;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.VideoView;

public class LiveActivity extends Activity {
    VideoView videoView;

    private AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog;
    String httpLiveUrl = "http://38.96.148.147:1935/live/livestream/playlist.m3u8";

    // =============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        // if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
        // Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // getWindow().clearFlags(
        // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        // getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // }
        // setContentView(R.layout.live);

    }

    // =============================================================================

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_shada, menu);
        MenuItem fullItem = menu.findItem(R.id.fullScreen);
        MenuItem smallItem = menu.findItem(R.id.smallScreen);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            fullItem.setVisible(false);
            smallItem.setVisible(true);
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            smallItem.setVisible(false);
            fullItem.setVisible(true);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    // =============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.live);
        try {
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
            videoView.requestFocus();

            videoView
                    .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            videoView.seekTo(1000);
                            videoView.start();

                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            errorDialog.setMessage("مشكلة في البث");
            errorDialog.setCancelable(true);
            errorDialog.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        // click listener on the alert box
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog errorStream = errorDialog.create();
            errorStream.show();
        }

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }

    // =============================================================================

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.shadatv.MainActivity"));
            break;

        case R.id.smallScreen:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            break;

        case R.id.fullScreen:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

But I find out another problem at optionsMenu. When I press about button to get out from this activity and run MainActivity, the app stops. What is wrong?

Comment: why you are not using this way to call activity.
Intent intent = new Intent(LiveActivity .this,Main.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: It looks like this answer poses a new question at the end. We prefer questions not to contain that - can the end bit be removed and allow the answer still to be useful, or is it better that the answer is removed entirely?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your AndroidManifest, you are telling Android: "Don't do the default reset when the keyboard is pulled out, or the phone is rotated; I want to handle this myself.

so the portrait layout will not set on your activity when the screen orientation changed.
why you are using `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation` **?**

Comment: because i convert from landscape to portrait and vice versa dynamically from optionsMenu

Comment: so i think you have to setContentView(R.layout.portrait); dynamically onclick.

Comment: THANKS I SOLVED IT BUT THERE IS ANOTHER PROBLEM I EXPLAIN IT IN MY ANSWER. COULD YOU HELP ME PLEASE??